# How do I fix this roue-related problem in my Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with Vue 3, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).

I am currently working on a search functionality and I found out it has a bug.

I have the "search-box" in `src\components\TopBar.vue`:

```
<template>
   <form class="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input v-on:keyup="debounceMovieSearch" v-model="searchTerm" class="form-control search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search movies...">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn" type="button">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'search']" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if="isSearch" @click="isSearch = false" class="search-results shadow-sm">
      <div v-if="this.movies.length">
        <router-link v-for="movie in movies.slice(0, 10)" :key="movie.id" :to="`/movie/${movie.id}`">
          <SearchItem :movie="movie" />
        </router-link>
      </div>

      <div v-else>
        <p class="m-0 p-2 text-center">No movies found for this search</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import env from '../env';
  import SearchItem from './SearchItem.vue';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'TopBar',

    components: {SearchItem},

    data() {
      return {
        isSearch: false,
        searchTerm: '',
        timeOutInterval: 1000,
        movies: []
      }
    },

    methods: {
      debounceMovieSearch() {
        setTimeout(this.doMovieSearch, this.timeOutInterval)
      },

      doMovieSearch() {
        if (this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
            this.isSearch = true;
            axios.get(`${env.api_url}/search/movie?api_key=${env.api_key}&query=${this.searchTerm}`).then(response => {
            this.movies = response.data.results;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      },
    }
});
</script>
```

In `src\components\SearchItem.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <span class="movie-poster">
    <img :src="moviePoster" :alt="movie.title" />
  </span>
  <span class="movie-title">{{ movie.title }}</span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SearchItem",

  props: {
    movie: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      genericMoviePoster: require("../assets/generic-poster.png"),
    };
  },

  computed: {
    moviePoster() {
      return !this.movie["poster_path"]
        ? this.genericMoviePoster
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie["poster_path"]}`;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

In `src\router\index.ts`:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue';
import TopRatedMoviesView from '../views/TopRatedMoviesView.vue';
import MovieDetailsView from '../views/MovieDetailsView.vue';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/top-rated',
    name: 'top_rated',
    component: TopRatedMoviesView
  },
  {
    path: '/movie/:id',
    name: 'movie_details',
    component: MovieDetailsView
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

#### Stackblitz

I have put together a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-68kyvk)**.

#### The problem

When clicking on one of the search results under the search box (as illustrated in the screenshots), I am *only directed to the movie details* if on the *homepage or the top-rated* path.

[image: Working!]

If I am *already* on the a movie details page, when I click on one of the search results, I am not redirected (to a new movie), as intended.

[image: Not working!]

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz of it ? that would help us to understand it more

Comment: also did you make sure vue understand that route has been changed ?

Comment: @TechnoTech I added the Stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not about the router the issue is about rendering the movie details after the user get redirected to a different `movie/id`, when the user get redirected you don't update the movie details in `MovieDetails.vue` because you only render the movie details using `mounted()` function, this function only get called once in the component life cycle, what you should do now is add a `watch` to watch for redirection changes and update the component, in `MovieDetails.vue` add the following code:

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.id'(newId) {
      this.getMovieDetails();
      this.getMovieTrailers();
      this.getMovieCast();
    }
  }
```

Comment: How should the entire component look, in tour opinion?

Comment: the component looks good to me, just add the above code before or after mounted(){..}

Comment: It does work, but I would appreciate some (short) explanation and or links to relevant tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: @RazvanZamfir for me the Vue documentation was enough, you can check it out, it's good https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html

Comment: There is actually no need for the `newId` argument to the function.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir yes in this case, but if you need it in a function inside the watch for example this.getMovieDetails(newId), you will pass it just like the code above, otherwise you can remove it